# Exception occurred while initializing the installation: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have Worker Services as Windows services which I am trying to install on a machine however it throws the below error when I try Installing it

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility Version 4.8.3752.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\JNyingi\source\repos\SeSPWS\SeSPWS\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\SeSPWS.exe' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest..
```

Below is the `.csproj` file content of the packages in use

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>dotnet-SeSPWS-00EEA7BA-8CD9-4E72-B073-FB0FB7B9192A</UserSecretsId>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <StartupObject />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.4.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.4.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.4.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.4.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

While looking at assembly binding log viewer I this error log.

```
** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (2/14/2020 @ 1:41:17 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80131018. No description available.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = C:\Users\JNyingi\source\repos\SeSPWS\SeSPWS\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\SeSPWS.exe
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = InstallUtil.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/JNyingi/source/repos/SeSPWS/SeSPWS/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.0/SeSPWS.exe.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Users\JNyingi\source\repos\SeSPWS\SeSPWS\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\SeSPWS.exe
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
ERR: Error extracting manifest import from file (hr = 0x80131018).
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x80131018.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131018). Probing terminated.
```

I have installed the following runtime; .NET Core 3.0, ASP.NET Core 3.0 and Windows desktop 3.0. However, the service still fails to install even after upgrading to .NET Core 3.1 runtime.

Below is my build profile

[image: Build Setup]

I have built a similar worker service before which installed without any hustle; kindly I wish to resolve this error and deploy the service to the machine.

**EDIT**
Below is My Program Class

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));
            if (isService)
            {
                CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsService();
            }
            else
            {
                CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
        }


        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseContentRoot(Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName))
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
                {
                    serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(1042);
                    serverOptions.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.5);
                });
    }
```

**EDIT2**
[image: nUGET packages]
These are the NuGet packages in use for the service

Comment: Most likely you have bitness problem

Comment: Change the AnyCPU in the build profile to x86 and try again, then change it to x64 and see any difference

Comment: I have checked the bitness and the output is 64bit @MichaelRandall

Comment: @CaiusJard let met try

Comment: @CaiusJard both fail with the same error

Comment: @CaiusJard and l I have added the Program.cs class

Comment: from your logs it appears you're using 64bit InstallUtil, if you're project is 32bit , attempt with c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in majority of the cases is caused due to *Incompatible* *bitness* of your `Application`|`Platform`|`Installutil|IIS`

*I've put together the various checks you can perform:*

- Settings of your main project `Project > Properties > Uncheck Prefer 32 bit`
- Settings of your main project `Project > Properties > /platform:AnyCpu` or the BITness that you're targetting `(x86) for 32bit`
- If you are referencing additional DLL(s) in your project, ensure there is no BITness mismatch
- Validate your `App.Config` file and see if you have lines it it which specifies a different target runtime versus the one targetted by your app
- Verify the bitness set by IIS > AppPool > `Enable 32 bit applications`
- Unchecking `"Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for Web Sites and Projects"` option under the `Projects and Solutions`
- Check the version of the `InstallUtil` that you are using to install the service
- Check the `StartUp` of your project and see if its the intended one
- Try to run InstallUtil is run as admin (As seen from another post)
- Uncheck 64 bit version of IIS from VS `Navigate to Visual Studio – Tools – Options – Projects and Solutions – Web Projects`
- Verify the bitness by viewing `.CSProj` file
- You can narrow down further by identifying the assembly that caused this exception by using [FusionLogging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/e74a18c4(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) *OR* [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) tool, you will be able to tell which dll failed to loadat runtime

**Further Reading:**

This [Medium](https://medium.com/@tocalai/create-windows-service-using-net-core-console-application-dc2f278bbe42) post explains the process of creating a Windows Service in .NetCore

---

**EDIT:** *Break down of the Root Cause based on OP's post below*

- WebHostBuilder primarily allows us to configure and build a WebHost and is best suited for web apps.
  But with .net core 2.1 a new option “generic” Host was introduced that enabled developers to create console app that can run background tasks, create services and handle messages.
  See "Steve Gordons" article on [Generic Host for Windows Services](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/running-net-core-generic-host-applications-as-a-windows-service)
- When we create worker service template, we need a reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices` from nuget
  Now with this we can use IHostBuilder.UseWindowsService()
  There are 2 ways of using this (see details next point): Background worker service(uses `Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Worker`), Web App(`Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`) service sample, the difference being Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting package is referenced explicitily in the former one
  [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#app-configuration) article that explains this

  - `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`
    Now here you can use IWebHostBuilder
    But be sure to use this for a web app-based service that uses the Razor Pages or MVC frameworks. [A Good example](https://dzone.com/articles/running-aspnet-core-application-as-windows-service)
  - `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">`
    This type suits the majority of the requirements for windows service creation where the service needs to executes background tasks
- `<RuntimeIdentifier>` elements are used with Self Contained deployment and are used by .NET packages to represent platform-specific assets in NuGet packages

Comment: I've tried this to no avail, kindly note I have added the list of packages in my project

Comment: I'm running the 64bit version, have you managed to replicate the error?

Comment: why don't you switch all you parameters from the list above to 32bit and also use 32bit version  of instalutil which is usually located here C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe.

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate it, but I was researching on related topics

Comment: I did I'm sharing the solution in a few

Comment: @JohnNyingi, updated chat, fyi incase you weren't notified

Comment: Thank you so much for breaking it down for me. I had a difficult time resolving issues.

Comment: no worries, I will update the answer just so if anybody else stumbles upon this

Answer (score 1):

So after much frustrating dead ends, our Lady showed me how to resolve the error. It's really simple, I made three main changes to my application.

`.csproj` was updated to;

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
    <UserSecretsId>dotnet-SeSPWS-00EEA7BA-8CD9-4E72-B073-FB0FB7B9192A</UserSecretsId>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <StartupObject />
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.4.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.4.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.4.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.4.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I also changed my `program.cs` and changed from `IWebHostBuilder` to `IHostBuilder` as shown below;

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));
            if (isService)
            {
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();//.RunAsService();
            }
            else
            {
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
        }


        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseContentRoot(Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName))
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
                    {
                        serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(1042);
                        serverOptions.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.5);
                    });
                }).UseWindowsService();
    }
```

Just to make sure that the service builds with a specific version of `.Net Core SDK` I added the following `global.json`

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.0.100",
    "rollForward": "disable"
  }
}
```

I then  built and published.

**NOTE** : I have also noted `InstallUtil` does not work with ASP.NET Worker Service. So, you have to change and use `SC` to install your service.Like so;

`SC {SERVICENAME} binpath="{path-to-exe}"`

Comment: You forget the CREATE command to install the service: SC CREATE {SERVICENAME} binpath="{path-to-exe}"